# Stack Overflow in rather short (30 lines) program

Tags: c++

First of all, I am a beginner, and I don't know what a StackOverflow even is, so please keep your explanations layman-friendly. I read a little about StackOverflow and was surprised that I encountered it even though my program is rather trivial. Anyway, I was practicing in Codewars and then this happened:
[image: stackoverflow]

The challenge:

> You are given two strings. In a single move, you can choose any of them, and delete the first (i.e. leftmost) character.

For Example:

By applying a move to the string "where", the result is the string "here".
By applying a move to the string "a", the result is an empty string "".
Implement a function that calculates the minimum number of moves that should be performed to make the given strings equal.

Notes
Both strings consist of lowercase Latin letters.
If the string is already empty, you cannot perform any more delete operations.*/

My code:

```
void change(std::string & x, std::string & y)
{
    std::string temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

long long shiftLeft(std::string largeString, std::string smallString)
{
  if(largeString.size() < smallString.size())
        change(largeString, smallString); 
    std::string sharedPart;
    int result(0);
    // Find the shared substring in both strings
    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < largeString.length(); ++i)
    {
        if(smallString.find(largeString.substr(i, largeString.length() - i)) != std::string::npos)
         {
             sharedPart = largeString.substr(i, largeString.length() - i);
             break;
         }
    }
    
    // If string is empty, return total length of the two strings
    if(sharedPart.empty())
        return largeString.length() + smallString.length();
    
    // Erase strings from the front until they're equal to the shared substring and count the letters erased
    while(largeString != sharedPart)
    {
        largeString.erase(largeString.begin());
        ++result;
    }

    while(smallString != sharedPart)
    {
        smallString.erase(smallString.begin());
        ++result;
    }

    // Return total of letters erased
    return result;

}
```

Please try to point out my mistake without spoiling the challenge for me.

Comment: [edit] and show a [mcve]

Comment: Usually a stack overflow is caused by allocating an array that's too big to fit on the stack, or by having runaway recursion. It's not clear what is going on in this case. I think you're missing the problematic code.

Comment: fwiw, large part of the challenge of writing correct and working code *is* testing and debugging. Writing code is not so much about writing correct code at the first try ;) Nevertheless I like your last sentence

Comment: What does `main` look like? Also, strings should be passed by reference (`long long shiftLeft(const std::string& largeString, const std::string& smallString)`)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I would've not post it here and quietly debugged it if I knew what a stackoverflow even is.

Comment: I was just trying to debunk a misunderstanding, not saying that this question should not have been asked. Did you try to use a debugger?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes There is no main. The format all challenegs in Codewars is to write standalone functions.

Comment: if you want to do testing and debugging you need to write your own main, because to test you need to be in control of input and output and everything. Once you know it works you can still put it in the sites environment

Comment: The real challenge here is to write a simple function which only calculates the number of moves, without creating any new string.

Comment: Hint: consider the reversed strings.

Comment: If I understand the problem statement correctly, you don't need to actually trim the strings (apply the moves), you could just compare their characters.

Comment: Please consider taking a look to those references: [`rbegin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin), [`std::mismatch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) (and maybe [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)).

Comment: @Bob__ I solved it according to the limited knowledge I have; That's why it's ungraceful and inefficient. Nevertheless, you have my thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function that does what you state:

```
size_t challange(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    auto l1 = s1.size();
    auto l2 = s2.size();
    for(size_t ind = 0;;++ind)
    {
        if(ind>=l1||ind>=l2||s1[l1-1-ind]!=s2[l2-1-ind])
        {
            return l1-ind+l2-ind;
        }
    }
}
```

PS: your challenge would be to figure out how this works :D

Every thread has a region in memory referred to as the stack. The stack is used to implement function calls. It stores return addresses, function parameters and local variables. Excessive use of any of which would result in stack being filled. This situation is called stack overflow. A very deep function call chain, like an endless recursion and very large local variable are common causes of this problem. The code you posted shows non of these. So I guess the problem originates elsewhere. As you mentioned Codewars, the problem may be because some of the test cases of this problem somehow test your function by using it recursively, and your function happens to have a particular error causing the recursion to go forever to at least very deep.